# Presheaves in a quasi-topos.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I do believe it is a trivial question. But unfortunately I don't know where I can find an answer.

Where could I find the answer to the following question?

> If $S$ is a small category and $X$ is a [quasi-topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasitopos), is $\operatorname{Fun} (S, X)$ a quasi-topos? If the answer is "no", what would be a nice counterexample? Would it be **PsTop**?

Comment: Do you know the book 'Higher Topos Theory'? It might have an answer in there. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608040

Comment: @Berci Do you know what a quasitopos is? It's not a quasicategory!